# Using Both, `@font-face` And `<link ref="preload" as="font">` In The Header?

Tags: html, font-face, preload

Just wondering, what is the difference between putting the `@font-face` rules in a `<style>` tag in the header, or putting a `<link ref="preload" as="font">` in the header?

For example, Shopify's [Dawn theme](https://github.com/Shopify/dawn/blob/main/layout/theme.liquid) has both, first the `@font-face` in some `<style>` tag at line 44, then the `<link>` at line 224.  Will this choice improve performance?

It makes intuitively more sense to me to use the `<link>` when the `@font-face` rule sits in some external stylesheet, which has to be downloaded first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the `<style>` tag will only load the fonts that are used in the document, while the the `<link>` tag will load all the fonts and store, so that they are ready to be used right away when necessary.. that's how I understand them